# How to use Paypal API with payflow pro

Tags: paypal

I have a site which runs smoothly with PayPal and  express checkout.  NOw my client wants a refrence transaction (billed directly from customer when he ordered via cellphone etc without involving him). He asked me to use payflow pro for this but I am really really confused how to use payflow pro with paypal API. Please Guide me . I already read their payflow guideness PDF but didn't get any idea from there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payflow Pro is an entirely different set of API calls, separate from PayPal.
Is your client sure he wants to use the Payflow Pro API, if he has already integrated with PayPal Express Checkout?
If all you want to do is a reference transaction, all you have to do is add 'L_BILLINGTYPE0=MerchantInitiatedBilling' to your initial SetExpressCheckout API call and call the DoReferenceTransaction API call to create this reference transaction.

Comment: Hi Robert Thanks for your reply. Here is the complete situation

1 . Site running with checkout of Express checkout and normal checkout of paypal
     NOw here if the customer orders with Paypal in a normal way.Means first gives your full information of shipping etc and then goes to paypal site to pay and complete your order. here my question is that that is it possible to do a refrence transaction of that order using payflow pro . Or we have to use another way for it.

Comment: Why insist on Payflow Pro, though? If you change the existing integration a little bit, you can do reference transactions on all EC transactions (assuming you get approved for reference transactions by PayPal)

Comment: Thanks for reply
Is it possible that we use the credit card for paypal refrence transaction using paypal API

Comment: Yes. You can call the DoReferenceTransaction API on transactions created via the DoDirectPayment API call.